# Unitary equivalence of matrices with equal trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

It is obvious that $B = OAO^\dagger$ have equal trace if $O$ is Hermian. But is is also so that:

$Tr(A) = Tr(B) \rightarrow A = OBO^\dagger$

For some Hermitian $O$ ?

I know this should be trivial to prove/disprove but Is just can't get it sorted out...

Comment: Ps: sorry for the bad Tex. Stackexchange doen't deel to like me phone's dollar sign :/

Comment: What do you mean by $O^{\dagger}?$

Comment: The hermitian conjugate

Comment: I think you mean that $O$ is *unitary* (and maybe that $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you meant that $O$ is *unitary*, and that $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.  If that's the case, your statement is not true.

Note that $OAO^\dagger$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$.  If we take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&0}
$$
Then we see that $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \operatorname{tr}(B)$.  Since they have different eigenvalues, however, there can be no unitary $O$ such that $B = OAO^\dagger$.

Answer (score 1):

I am that sure that I understood your question, but I suppose that $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is a counter-example.